# A split function with two arguments returns error

Tags: python, split, tabs, delimiter

I tried to write a very simple code in python because I did not understand how `line.split` is working if we have two parameters. However, this code returns an error and I also did not understand the purpose of the `line.split`. Can you please help me?

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

word = None
count = 0
line= 'foo     1' \
      ''

line = line.strip()
try:
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
except:
    print('error')

count = int(count)
print(word, count)
```

Comment: If you mask the error message (using `try` and a bare `except`) with your own custom message, how would you see the actual error?

Comment: @Austin I get a value error, not enugh values to unpack

Comment: I know. I was telling that you should not use `except` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Split returns a single list of strings split based on the delimiter you pass it.

`'hey, you'.split(',')` returns `['hey', ' you']` which can be unpacked if you provide two variables.

If the string you are splitting splits into a list of more than two values then you will have an error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

In your case just check what the output of `split` is, it may be a list containing only one element `foo    1`, which cannot be unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

`line.split('\t')` is returning only one value, and by `word, count` you are expecting two, so it results in the error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

If you change that line to `word, count = line.split()` without any parameter in the split function, it will split on any whitespace by default, and it correctly returns the two values you expect with no errors.

Comment: I am sorry,  line.split('\t', 1) was in my code, i accidentally deleted the ,1 part.

Comment: @MaryPoppins Ok, that doesn't make a difference in this situation. `line.split('\t', 1)` still returns just one value.

Comment: error
None 0  This is what the code returns if i replace with line.split() . However, what should i do to use '\t' as a delimiter and return both the word value (the first one) and the count value (the second one)?

Comment: I just did the replacement and ran it and it returns `foo 1`. There's something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

What error message is returned, exactly? If it's a `ValueError` caused by the `line.split('\t')` line, then it probably means that the string doesn't actually contain a tab character, but a number of spaces. If you want to split the string on either tabs or spaces, omit the argument: `line.split()`

Comment: Then your string does not contain an actual Tab character (`'\t'`), so there is nothing to split, so the resulting list contains only a single value (not two of them), as has been pointed out by several answers.

Answer (score 0):

Easy,,, [source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

```
result = your_string.split(separator, max)
```

**separator**   *Optional.* Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string. *Default value is a whitespace*
**max** *Optional.* Specifies how many splits to do. *Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences"*

---

python string split returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator.

So you cannot have `word, count = line.split('\t', 1)`

just use `words= line.split('\t')`

Comment: I used a program for inspiration which has exactly word, count = line.split('\t', 1) and it works perfectly. It has a text with many lines like mine which comes from sys.stdin, and for line in (that input) it performs exactly this kind of action and it works. Do you have any idea why